# Cannot call javascript function from signalR call back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, signalr

I have a html page which includes javascript.  In this page i call 3 ajax calls and wait until they are all done.

I'm using signalR and trying to update the UI from the onMessageReceivedSyncTasks() function.  If i call a jquery selector within here it works fine.  But.. if i try and call the function IntitalLoad() i get an error.  Its all in the same scope?

Settings.html

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- html code not included -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   function InitialLoad() {
            $.when(GetSettings(), GetTimebands(), GetApnList()).done(function (a1, a2, a3) {
               // UI changes when all 3 ajax functions done
            });
    }

    function GetSettings() {
            return $.ajax({
              // ajax call 1
            });
    }
    function GetTimebands() {
            return $.ajax({
              // ajax call 2
            });
    }
    function GetApnList() {
            return $.ajax({
             // ajax call 3
             });
    }
  });
 <script src="/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script> <-- microsoft signalr lib -->
 <script src="/signalr/dist/browser/messagebroker.js"></script>
</body>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Messagebroker.js

```
signalrConnection.on("onMessageReceivedSyncTasks", function (eventMessage) {

   if ($('#table_buttons').length) {
        $('#table_buttons').DataTable().ajax.reload();  // This selector works fine
   }

   InitialLoad();  // Calling a function returns error
   
});
```

Error:

```
 [2021-11-05T13:21:33.643Z] Error: A callback for the method onmessagereceivedsynctasks threw error 'ReferenceError: InitialLoad is not defined'.
```

Comment: Your `InitialLoad` is scoped inside document.ready, so is not globally available for a callback - take the function definition outside doc.ready and only put things you *need* to be there in doc.ready (ie, in your provided code, you don't need/want doc.ready at all)

Comment: Thanks, its working, had me stumped